# Is it possible to add disks to an existing RAID 5 array?

Tags: raid

Suppose I have a RAID 5 array consisting of 4 disks. If I buy two new disks later, can I add them non-destructively to the existing RAID 5 array?

It could be a hardware RAID controller or Windows Server 2003 software RAID.

Comment: Per the [ServerFault FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq#dontask), hypothetical questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Hardware RAID controller: Depends on the controller. Read the manual or check with the vendor. It's certainly possible.

Windows Software RAID: No

Answer (score 0):

Well, here we go - it depends. "Could be a car or a truck" is not specific, and this dependes on specific models. Most PROPER hardware raid controllers allow that - some cheap ones do not.